# How to get the value deep inside JSON?

Tags: android, json

This is the sample JSON output:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "routes": [ {
    "summary": "I-40 W",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
      },
      ...
      ... additional steps of this leg
    ...
    ... additional legs of this route
      "duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
      "start_location": {
        "lat": 35.4675602,
        "lng": -97.5164276
      },
      "end_location": {
        "lat": 34.0522342,
        "lng": -118.2436849
      },
      "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
      "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
    } ],
    "copyrights": "Map data ©2010 Google, Sanborn",
    "overview_polyline": {
      "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOnzh@vlbBtc~@tsE`vnApw{A`dw@~w\\|tNtqf@l{Yd_Fblh@rxo@b}@xxSfytAblk@xxaBeJxlcBb~t@zbh@jc|Bx}C`rv@rw|@rlhA~dVzeo@vrSnc}Axf]fjz@xfFbw~@dz{A~d{A|zOxbrBbdUvpo@`cFp~xBc`Hk@nurDznmFfwMbwz@bbl@lq~@loPpxq@bw_@v|{CbtY~jGqeMb{iF|n\\~mbDzeVh_Wr|Efc\\x`Ij{kE}mAb~uF{cNd}xBjp]fulBiwJpgg@|kHntyArpb@bijCk_Kv~eGyqTj_|@`uV`k|DcsNdwxAott@r}q@_gc@nu`CnvHx`k@dse@j|p@zpiAp|gEicy@`omFvaErfo@igQxnlApqGze~AsyRzrjAb__@ftyB}pIlo_BflmA~yQftNboWzoAlzp@mz`@|}_@fda@jakEitAn{fB_a]lexClshBtmqAdmY_hLxiZd~XtaBndgC"
    },
    "warnings": [ ],
    "waypoint_order": [ 0, 1 ],
    "bounds": {
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 34.0523600,
        "lng": -118.2435600
      },
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 41.8781100,
        "lng": -87.6297900
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

How do I get the value of distance ? Here is what I tried but failed.

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(mJsonResults.toString());

                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");

                JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
                JSONObject value = distance.getJSONObject("text");
                Log.d("Distance", value.toString());
```

And there is no output from logcat. But when I tried `Log.d("Distance",distance.toString());` the value I get is `D/Distance﹕ {"value":43481,"text":"43.5 km"}`

All I want to get is the value of "text" inside "distance". How should I do it ?

**My code is getting from another JSON data but it has the same format as the JSON sample above**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had missed parsing the steps JsonArray and made some issues in fetching distance

```
JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray legsArray = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
JSONObject legs = legsArray.getJSONObject(0);


JSONArray stepsArray = routes.getJSONArray("steps");
JSONObject steps = stepsArray.getJSONObject(0);

JSONObject distanceObject = steps.getJSONObject("distance");


String text = distance.getString("text");
String value = distance.getString("value");
```